# is there picturebox in java SE application(using netbeans)

Tags: java, picturebox

is there picturebox in java SE application(using netbeans).  i dont want to use label and Imageicon. can someone help me .

Comment: I don't know what a picture box is, but what is wrong with a JLabel and an Icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. The JDK itself doesn't offer that many ready components - if you want something more - either create it yourself (by creating a class extending `JComponent` or `JPanel` for instance) or have a look at what external Swing libraries have to offer. You can bend and swing the JLabel + ImageIcon approach to your will easily. Btw this is probably the fifth consecutive question you're asking for a trivial topic. You'd do better to read a good Java book for beginners like "[Core Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354764)" or google a bit, instead of flooding SO with your questions. It will be a much more productive approach for you as well...

Comment: This is a sure path to `OutOfMemoryError`, especially if you try to zoom in on the image.